# Publish unknown number of topics?

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to adapt the Euclidean Cluster Extraction tutorial from PCL to work with ROS.

I can get the tutorial working as it should, my question is with handling the detected clusters.

My idea was to publish each cluster in a different topic so I can look at them separately in rviz. My question is how can I do that?

Currently I'm creating one publisher as a global variable, and using `nodehandle.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>()` in `main()` to create a topic and publish on it. This means that I can only publish only one pointcloud through this.

Is it possible to create a number of publishers, unknown at compile time, since I don't know how many objects will be detected, that each publish on a different topic?

How else would you recommend I use/view the vector of PointClouds that get created by the cluster extraction? The tutorial extracts them to files, but I would rather view them in rviz somehow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95531/publish-unknown-number-of-topics?/) by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just create multiple `Publisher` within your node dynamically. They don't need to be static variables.

As to viewing them: That might be annoying as you need to add an extra display for each. For clustering I'd rather send one point cloud with colors and choose a random color per cluster.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on 2013-10-29**:
But how can I get access to my nodehandler in the callback function, where the Publishers would be dynamically created? Is it possible to pass a reference to it in the callback?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-29**:
If you mean the NodeHandle you can create those on the fly.

**Comment by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on 2013-10-29**:
OK what I've tried now is:

-Create a vector of publishers inside the callback function.
-In a for loop initialize the publishers, using  `nodehandle.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>()`
-Convert the cluster clouds to ros, and publish them.
My problem is that apart from the first publisher, all the other publishers do not receive messages.

Is there some other way to publish the different clouds in different topics?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-29**:
If you publish immediately after creating, there won't be a connection yet. Try waiting until getNumSubscribers is > 0 or create a bunch of publishers ahead.

**Comment by [Barbas](https://answers.ros.org/users/6891/barbas/) on 2013-10-29**:
Thanks, for the help, got it working now. Here a gist of the code, if anyone wants to take a look:

https://gist.github.com/Barbas/7220227

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-08-21**:
Sorry, I know this is a really old post, but would you happen to have that code available? @Barbas

**Comment by [kerollosghobrial](https://answers.ros.org/users/24333/kerollosghobrial/) on 2015-10-31**:
hello Barbas,
i want use your concept for publishing unknown topic, can you send your code again because this link does not work. thanks in advance.

**Comment by [alfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/55261/alfan/) on 2020-05-27**:
i know its very old post, but can i see your code please? i'm facing the same problem right now

**Comment by [alfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/55261/alfan/) on 2020-05-27**:
this is the code

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Barbas/7220227/raw/ec0f2231ba4f1999200da7cda87e23dfb7141622/cluster_extraction.cpp